# Select the first item by default in a Master Detail flow

Tags: android, master-detail

I'm working on a screen for a Android app where the screen design is a Master Detail flow with a list view on the left, and a changing form on the right (similar to the wizard design in HTML)

I noticed that when the screen is first created, the right side of the screen is empty, until I manually 'click' on the first item, then it will only load the first fragment. My question is, is it possible that i load the first item by default?

I'd tried by adding the following code in the onViewCreated function in the ListFragment class . It will show the right sided screen but without the list view on the left.

```
getListView().requestFocusFromTouch();
getListView().setSelection(position);
getListView().performItemClick(getListView().getAdapter().getView(position, null, null), position, position);
```

Anyone has any idea how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Select first item by default in ListView in Master Detail template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21216261/android-select-first-item-by-default-in-listview-in-master-detail-template)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

End up i manage to get things work by using the code below:

```
fragment.getListView().requestFocusFromTouch();
fragment.getListView().setSelection(position);
fragment.getListView().performItemClick(fragment.getListView().getAdapter().getView(position, null, null), position, position);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about writing a method to handle the ListView ItemClick event, and call this method in onCreate?

Comment: Can you elaborate your suggestion by supporting it with an example code?